# Getting unique elements and intersection of two (or x) lists efficiently

Tags: algorithm, sorting, set, array-difference

If I have two (or more) lists, I would like to get all parts of the "venn diagram" made by those lists: i.e. elements unique to A, elements unique to B, and the intersection of A and B.

The "standard", but also naive, way of getting such a result would be using two loops, by going through all of A and checking if the elements are in B or not, thus getting the results of `A_unique` and `intersection`. By then looping through B and checking if the elements are in A, we would get `B_unique`.

Most languages have some kind of intersect or difference function implemented in their standard libraries, but they usually work that way anyway.

However, this seems extremely inefficient. Is there a better way / algorithm of getting those three parts, without having to loop twice (and perhaps even without using standard "contains" calls on the other list, which usually loops through that list as well, thus making each loop O(n^2)...)?

Would it perhaps already be an improvement to make both lists be queues, and pop the first item on each loop, thus reducing the amount of subsequent checks?

Comment: Are you familiar with Python `set`?  What's your performance req. - just faster than loops?

Comment: You are assumptin that intersect and difference "work that way" is not correct.  They are implemented O(n).

Comment: @DanielHao I guess a Set would indeed be better due to faster contains-lookups, but then you would have to first construct the set on both lists. While it is definitely more performant on big inputs (O(n) instead of O(n^2)), I'm not so sure about small inputs, since it would be the equivalent of another for loop. I mean, for my usecase I'm honestly optimizing for absolutely no reason, but having two separate loops for this kind of issue just feels so inelegant and inperformant.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Is that really a fair assumption for most languages though? Perhaps C++ std is well implemented, but can the same be said about e.g. dart? Not sure why, but when it comes to performance topics, I've learnt / been told to stay away from standard implementations, *especially* if I don't actually know what's under the hood. Not that it matters for my usecase here, though. But even if I were to use difference/intersect: It would still be 2-3 different calls, one for uniqueA, one for uniqueB, one for intersect. And it just "feels" like this problem should be solved using a single 1

Comment: Sort the lists, and scan the lists. If A[i] == B[j], add that element to `intersection`, and increment both indexes. If A[i] < B[j], add A[i] to `A_unique` and increment `i`. Likewise for `A[i] > B[j]`.

Comment: @Fly: No need to make both lists into sets; you only need to do the lookup in one of them. Anyway, making a set should be O(N). Also, I wouldn't discard standard libraries so cavalierly. Sometimes you have a problem (like, perhaps, this one) which can be more efficiently solved as a special case because the standard library doesn't anticipate the specialised use case, but if you have a problem which directly corresponds to a standard library function, it's probably a good idea to benchmark before reinventing rotary transportation tools.

Comment: @Fly for This simple thing?  Yes, it is fair to say that most languages will implement this in  O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single loop in (at least) two ways, with a preprocessing step. The following algorithms assume that neither list has duplicate elements; modifying it to handle duplicate elements is simpler with the second algorithm but can be done with the first one as well.

#### With a hash set.

1. Create a hash table from list A. (Perhaps better, from the smaller of the lists, but I'm going to write this as if it's list A.)
2. Create empty lists *Only B* and *In Both*
3. For each element in B:

   - If it's not in the hash table, put in in *Only B*.
   - If it's in the hash table, remove it and put in *In Both*.
4. When you're done with the loop, whatever is left in the hash table is *Only A*.

#### Using heaps / priority queues

1. Use `makeheap` to turn both lists into min heaps
2. While both heaps have elements:

   - If the smallest element in A is (strictly) less than the smallest element in B, remove it and put it in *Only A*.
   - Otherwise, if the smallest element in B is (strictly) less than the smallest element in A, remove it and put it into *Only B*
   - Otherwise, the smallest element of both heaps are equal. Remove both of them and put one in *In Both*.
3. When one heap is empty, put all the elements of the other heap into *Only A* or *Only B*, depending on which heap still has elements left. If you want the new sets to be sorted, use the heap's `remove-min` method; if you don't care, you can save a few cycles by just copying from the underlying array.

You can run this algorithm in-place to avoid memory allocations, as long as you don't care about the order of the resulting lists, by keeping *In Both* at the end of one (or both) of the originals, maintaining a partition point, which is initially at the very end (indicating that the *In Both* list is empty). Instead of putting an element present in both lists into a separate data structure, you remove it as usual from its heap, which moves it to the beginning of the free space, then swap it with the element just before the partition point, and finally move the partition back one element.